# Could not find DHCP daemon to get information on Belkin G Wifi Router

Tags: wireless-router, dhcp

I am using a Belkin G Wireless Router F5D7234, and i have a DSL connection with only a ethernet cable. So i connected the cable to the Modem port and allowed it to use Dyanmic IP, it worked successfully and an ip was assigned to it and multiple computers could connect to it and browse. But after some time the power went off and after then upon rebooting it is taking about half hour to get an IP address. Upon seeing the log i see this entry repeatedly

```
07/02/2010 23:22:34 DHCP Client: [WAN]Could not find DHCP daemon to get information
07/02/2010 23:22:32 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
07/02/2010 23:22:30 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
07/02/2010 23:22:28 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
07/02/2010 23:22:26 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
07/02/2010 23:22:26 DHCP Client: [WAN]Could not find DHCP daemon to get information
07/02/2010 23:22:24 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
07/02/2010 23:22:22 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
07/02/2010 23:22:20 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
07/02/2010 23:22:18 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
```

Any idea what i can do? I tried using another belkin router of same model and make and there also i faced the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Belkin Wireless N router, and recently had the same issue.

```
08/28/2015 15:26:17 DHCP Client: [WAN]Could not find DHCP daemon to get information
08/28/2015 15:26:15 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
08/28/2015 15:26:12 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
08/28/2015 15:26:10 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
08/28/2015 15:26:08 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
08/28/2015 15:26:08 DHCP Client: [WAN]Could not find DHCP daemon to get information
```

The problem kept re-occurring when I cycled the router power, but when I went to the DHCP Cient List (on the router's gui page--get there by typing the router's IP address into a browser) and hit "refresh", this solved the problem for me. Hitting refresh causes the router to reset the list; if you have been using your router with another modem (like me), this may work to get the router to recognize the new modem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that turned out to be simple and may be the issue you have. My wireless router was connected to a Motorolla cable modem.  It turns out that the cable modem only does DHCP ONCE and then doesn't dish out any more DHCP address or responds.

The solution?  reset the cable modem.

So go on, try resetting your modem/router.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea what i can do? I tried using another belkin router of same model and make and there also i faced the same problem.

This does not look like a problem with the router. It looks like a problem on the WAN side. In other words, a problem with whatever is on the other side of the ethernet port you connect the WAN port of your Belkin F5D7234 router to.

```
07/02/2010 23:22:34 DHCP Client: [WAN]Could not find DHCP daemon to get information  
07/02/2010 23:22:32 DHCP Client: [WAN]Send Discover
```

The [Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) starts by sending out a request for configuration info on the network it is connected to. Because your router has no idea what the network address of any DHCP servers might be, it broadcasts a "Discover Packet" and then waits for a server to reply to this request. If no response is received, then it just tries again. This is what you are seeing in the log.

Your router is not getting a response from a DHCP server. The DHCP server is either unreachable or not available. This is a problem which your ISP would need to fix. There is nothing that I know which you could do on your end.

Out of curiosity, are you positive your router should use the Dynamic IP setting? In this [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/157115/use-adsl-modem-as-wifi-router) you were working with an ISP connection which required a Static IP. What changed?

Comment: Hi John, It turned out it wasn't a static ip in the previous question. Right now we have configured it in PPPoE mode and it is working fine, am still clueless why the dynamic mode didn't work.